# Generating an MVP for an object

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

So I'm using GLM to generate a MVP for each specific model, like so: (Ignore the namespace errors, I am using namespace glm but sometimes I just like to write it in)

```
//Generate MVP
glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
glm::mat4 View = glm::lookAt(
    vec3(4, 4, 3),
    vec3(0, 0, 0),
    vec3(0, 1, 0)
    );
glm::mat4 Model = mat4(1.0f);

glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
```

If I want my model to be in a different place than the origin, should I simply change

```
glm::mat4 Model = mat4(1.0f);
```

to

```
glm::mat4 Model = glm::gtx::translate(x, y, z);
```

Comment: Incase you don't know glm the line I'm using now makes an identity matrix.

Comment: What is your question? Did you try this out? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't have access to a compiler right now, and the thought came to me so I pulled some code off of my web host from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that should do it. Think of it as placing your model relative to the world.